# JAVA is not showing in application after successfully installed

Tags: java, installation

Currently I had uninstalled Java6 from my mac. I tried installing Java 10 it did not install properly. One of my colleague bioinformatician uninstalled via terminal. The reinstallation of JAVA 10 or 8 or 6 is failing repeatedly. We tried via homebrewer as well. The java appears in system preferences but can not use it because not found in terminal when typed java -version. Neither Java folder is found in application support after installing. Did anyone faced this problem?
Currently using macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6

Comment: Have you set the `PATH` variable?

Comment: I tried but it was not possible

Comment: It is possible. Without setting the PATH variable it wont work

Comment: Terminal does not show java -version and java_home .. Please tell me if other way  to go ahead and set the path

Comment: ... you need to set the path before those can work. Use google to find it out

Comment: Are we talking about JRE or JDK? and also, could you confirm that you are using the correct installer for Java. ?

Comment: I tried JDK to install. I dowloaded java from main java oracle website